# Reading Grib Data in R - reading band names

Tags: r, rgdal, grib

Currently I can read grib files in R using rgdal, but I don't really know what are names of the bands this file contains. For example, below is a grib data I am working with.

http://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/s4pa//GLDAS_V1/GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H/2016/091/GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H.A2016091.2100.001.2016099220519.grb

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

fname = "GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H.A2016091.2100.001.2016099220519.grb"
gribdata = readGDAL(fname) 

summary(gribdata)

band01 = gribdata@data[[1]]
band28 = gribdata@data[[28]]
dim(band01) = c(1440,600)
dim(band28) = c(1440,600)
```

I can read the first and the 28th bands; but I don't know what are these bands (which parameters).

The "summary" function doesn't help either. Could you please help, how I learn the names of the bands this file contains?

Answer (score 0):

The [README](https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/GLDAS_V1/README.GLDAS.pdf) (same location you indicated) refers to [this page](https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/hydrology/data-holdings/parameters):

```
Parameters:

Water Balance parameters
086: Average layer soil moisture (# layers: CLM, 10; Mosaic, 3; Noah, 4; VIC, 3)
065: Snow water equivalent
071: Total canopy water storage
132: Rainfall rate
131: Snowfall rate
099: Snowmelt
235: Surface runoff
234: Subsurface runoff
057: Total evapotranspiration

Energy Balance parameters
111: Net shortwave radiation
112: Net longwave radiation
122: Sensible heat flux
121: Latent heat flux
155: Ground heat flux
138: Average surface temperature
085: Average layer soil temperature (# layers: CLM, 10; Noah, 4)

Forcing parameters
204: Surface incident shortwave radiation
205: Surface incident longwave radiation
011: Near surface air temperature
051: Near surface specific humidity
032: Near surface wind magnitude
001: Surface pressure
132: Rainfall rate (included in Water Balance)
131: Snowfall rate (included in Water Balance)

Static parameters
Elevation
Dominant vegetation type
Soil sand fraction
Soil silt fraction
Soil clay fraction
```